# Unable to start Kestrel (Address already in use) .NET Angular SPA Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I have built the docker image and run the container but I cannot access the app in the browser.
I have tried everything I found but none of the options worked for me.
The Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install wget gnupg \
    git \
    unzip
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:6001
EXPOSE 6001
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["project.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./project.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN mkdir -p /app/ClientApp/dist
COPY --from=nodebuilder /usr/src/app/dist/. /app/ClientApp/dis
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project.dll", ,  "--server.urls", "https://+:6001"]
```

The launchSettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:6001",
      "sslPort": 6001
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MaconomyRadiator": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": false,
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:6001;http://localhost:6000",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

There is no other process listening on port 6001 so I am not sure why this error appears when I run dotnet project.dll inside the container. Any suggestions?

Comment: IISExpress stays running. Shut it down, maybe even reboot

Comment: How do you run the container?

Comment: Just docker run -p 6001 image_name

Comment: Check if there are any stopped containers that use port 6001 and remove them. You can see them with `docker ps -a` or in Docker Desktop. Remove with `docker rm <container-name>` or Docker Desktop.

Comment: It's the only container I have

Comment: I see that in the docker file, you have `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:6001`  and `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project.dll", ,  "--server.urls", "https://+:6001"]` . You may be telling the runtime that both http and https are on 6001 port. Try changing the port number for one of them.  For https, you have to give the path for certificates which I don't see in your docker file. Adding the docker run command that you use in the question may help get more details on the issue.

Comment: while running the docker image you need to specify "-p 6001:6001" to be able to access from host machine browser